# Default login is not working in cakephp 3.2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I am a newbie to cakephp 3.2.I have done login using cakephp code ,
but there is a  need to create a default login (means irrespective of what is the login id and password is present in database,if i will give the default login username and password ,login will work.).

Below is code

```html
if(($data['email'] == 'admin@gmail.com') && ($data['password'] == '123456')) { 
    $getMasterLogin = $this->Users->find('all')->where(['Users.type' => 1])->first();
    $user = $this->Auth->identify($getMasterLogin);//pj($user);exit;//alaway returnig false
    //$this->Auth->setUser($user);
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

Here `$this->Auth->identify` is always returning false.
I have done login section as per cook book ,but i am not able to do this default login.I need it badly.
Sorry .
Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is a very very bad idea and opens your system to all sorts of hacking attacks. You should rather create a admin user in your database.

However, the answer to your actual question is:

`identify()` does not take any arguments, rather it authenticates based on the current request data, so if you do not have a user matching that data in your database it will alway return false. What you want to do is simply call `setUser($getMasterLogin)` as follows:

```
if(($data['email'] == 'admin@gmail.com') && ($data['password'] == '123456')) { 
    $getMasterLogin = $this->Users->find('all')->where(['Users.type' => 1])->first();
    $this->Auth->setUser($getMasterLogin);
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

You can join the CakePHP support slack channel through http://cakesf.herokuapp.com/ and you'll be able to ask questions and get answers in real time!

Comment: Yes its working ,but it need some modification.
Thank you for your kind help. : ) :) :) :) :)